# How to change BorderBrush of the DataGrid's Border by value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Hi I am trying to change BorderBrush property of the Border elemen in DataGrid depend on Value of the records.
For example if  record will have value = "Low" the BorderBrush will change color to Green
value = "Medium" the color will be yellow etc..
How can I achieve this? I made CellConverter, but how to use him for Border?

```
 <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Transparent" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                          //This one
                            <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"  CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                    
                                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <DataGridCellsPresenter ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    <DataGridDetailsPresenter Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                                    <DataGridRowHeader Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                
                            </Border>
                            
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
```

> CellConvertor class

```
 public class CellConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string input = value as string;
            switch (input)
            {
                case "High":
                return Brushes.Red;
                   
                case "Medium":
                    return Brushes.Yellow;
                    
                case "Low":
                    return Brushes.Green;
                default:
                    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behaviour in multiple ways.

1. You can have color property (even as `string`) that return based on property that returns "High", "Low", "Medium" values.

**ViewModel:**

```
private string _Colour { get; set; }
private string _Value { get; set; }

public string Colour
{
    get { return _Colour; }
}

public string Value 
{
    get { return _Value; }
    set
    {
        _Value = value;
        switch (_Value)
        {
            case "Low":
                Colour = "Green";
                break;
            case "Medium":
                Colour = "Yellow";
                break;
            case "High":
                Colour = "Red";
                break;
            default:
                Colour = null;
                break;
            
        }
        OnPropertyChanged("Colour");
        OnPropertyChanged("Value");
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<!--And other properties-->
<Border Background="{Binding Colour}"/>
```

2. The other way is thru converter although I would still return it as string

   ```
    internal class StringColourConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is not string) return null;
            switch (value)
            {
                case "Low":
                    return  "Green";
                case "Medium":
                    return  "Yellow";
                case "High":
                    return  "Red";
                default:
                    return  null;
            }
        }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
   ```

   }

but in this case binding is different and you have to reference this Converter;

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:AssemblyName.xamlconverters"
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:StringColourConverter x:Key="StrCol"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    
    <!--And other properties-->
    <Border Background="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource StrCol}}"/>
```

Also with Converter you dont need `Color` property on `ViewModel`

Comment: In ViewModel I have to implement PropertyChanged inteface, right? I also read, that I could this achieve by using Triggers?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that in many ways. 
For ViewModel you need property changed implementation for to update UI (thats one of the most important parts of MVVM). 
Personally, id use Converter if this is reocurring & bidning color if this is something needed only at this case and view.

Comment: I came up with something like that, but it doesn't change the color `BorderBrush="{Binding TypeOfAlert, Converter={StaticResource CellConverter}}" ` In `DataGrid`

Comment: You have to add resource to `DataGrid` it has different `DataContext` than your view. As it has changed once you applied data to it. See the edit i made on reply.

Comment: Okay, but what If I want to change`border` in control template? See in my example

Comment: `<style.resources>`